# Build failed with an exception. react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting this error while building app with command `react-native run-android`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9YbG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You installed an npm module that require linking, so try automatic linking through exec the following command in your terminal:

```
> react-native link
```

if it failed to solve your issue, then go to the documentation page of your npm module, and follow the steps for manual linking